# How to use React Native Debugger or Redux Dev Tools with Expo 50

Tags: reactjs, debugging, expo, native

For the last 8 months I've been building an app using React Native - I was using React Native Debugger for debugging which also has a Redux Dev Tools extensions so I could manually see how my redux store was working amongst other things.

Expo version 49 and 50 were released recently, I had to upgrade in order to use the Expo Go app and now none of the debuggers are working. Ive checked all over the internet and there doesnt seem to be any fix for this has anyone got any idea how i can get React Native Debugger back working?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

first you have to be sure your app engine is the hermes engine. ( it's the default with SDK 50, but you can still opt in to use JSC)
I think what you're looking for for debugging is installing an expo dev tool plugin. see:  https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/devtools-plugins/

there are popular plugins for popular frameworks already like the apollo client one, react-query and react-navigation AFAIK. however looks like you're a redux fan, there's a semi detailed step to making your own dev tool plugin, see: https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/create-devtools-plugins/

I'm not sure one for redux exists yet but maybe that can narrow your search if you don't want to create one